# Exchange email message not being sent through Powershell script

Tags: powershell, email, smtp, exchange-server

Good day,

The message for email users about expiring password is not being sent even though the script doesn't show any error message and runs successfully.

Need help investigating where is the issue. I have checked O365 exchange admin message trace and there is nothing.

Here is the code:

````
# Import Active Directory module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Set the maximum password age
$maxDays = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.TotalDays

# Define the email settings
$emailFrom = "myaccount@domain.com"
$smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$smtpPort = 587
$smtpUsername = "myaccount@domain.com"  # Replace with your SMTP username
$smtpPassword = "my account password"  # Replace with your SMTP password

# Create the SMTP client object
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, $smtpPort)
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($smtpUsername, $smtpPassword)
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true

# Define the OU and filter for Active Directory users
$OU = "OU=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx"
$filter = {
    Enabled -eq $true -and
    PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false -and
    Mail -ne $null
}

# Retrieve and process the Active Directory users within the specific OU
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope Subtree -LDAPFilter $filter -Properties pwdLastSet | Sort-Object pwdLastSet

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $lastSet = [System.DateTime]::FromFileTimeUtc($user.pwdLastSet)
    $expires = $lastSet.AddDays($maxDays).ToShortDateString()
    $daysToExpire = [math]::Round((New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date) -End $expires).TotalDays)
    $firstName = $user.Name

    if ($daysToExpire -eq 14) {
        $subject = "Jūsų slaptažodis baigs galioti už $daysToExpire dienas"
        $body = "$firstName, text"

        $smtp.Send($emailFrom, $user.Mail, $subject, $body)
    }
    elseif ($daysToExpire -eq 3) {
        $subject = "Jūsų slaptažodis baigs galioti už $daysToExpire dienas"
        $body = "$firstName, text"

        $smtp.Send($emailFrom, $user.Mail, $subject, $body)
    }
}```
````

Comment: You forgot to 'ask' to also get the property `mail` from the users on the `Get-ADUser` call, so `$user.Mail` will be $null

Comment: Also, your $filter should be a string and you're not using ldap syntax on it so at least `-LDAPFilter $filter` should be `-Filter $filter`

Comment: First thing I'd try is simply replacing those `$smtp.Send` lines with simply outputting the information to screen, eg `write-host "emailFrom - $($user.Mail) - $subject - $body"` and confirm what output you actually get, eg do you actually get any? That'll narrow down whether the issue is with the earlier query, or with how you're sending.